# Force re-render part of React component to make it update itself from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I download SVG image from remote server and render it in my React component using react-svg (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-svg):

```
<ReactSVG ref={this.svgRef} src={`http://localhost:3001/${this.state.firstName}${this.state.lastName}.svg`} />
```

As you can see, this svg uses template literals to form its name (svg's name depends on username stored in state).

Next I need to work with child elements in this svg. I do it using ref and then I set results to state:

```
const node = this.svgRef.current.childNodes[0];
node.forEach(e => {
   if (e.className.baseVal === 'one') {
     this.setState({
        something: e.className.baseVal
        })
      }
//etc etc
   })
```

And finally I want my page to be updated with this new state values. Say, I have

```
<Row className='border'>
  <Col className='border'>SomeCol</Col>
  <Col className='border'>{this.state.something}</Col>
</Row>
```

I want to update Col with this.state.something, but the problem is it doesn't update on render. How can I re-render only this part of my component? Should I make a separate component? Or are there any other good practices?

Comment: is all the code inside same component?

Comment: @Jagrati yes it is